# Need advice on creating an nft smart contract which hatches/changes into a new final image after some time!

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-721, nft

So I want an egg hatching nft, imagine a pokemongo egg and after some time has passed, the egg hatches into a new image which will be the final image of the nft.
Does anyone know of any ideas of how this can be done? is it even possible?

I first thought having the image in the metadata point to a dynamic file, however, that is not secure and defeats the purpose.

Or can this just be done in the smart contract itself where it modifies the image with a simple function in the code? Has this been done by anyone? Any tutorials? tips? code that does this?
is this just a basic dynamic smart contract?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, not a response, but I came here when googling the same. Did you find any useful resource/help for this?